# Visualforce object-specific action in Salesforce1

Tags: salesforce1-platform

In Salesforce1, I want to redirect back to Salesforce1 on a command button after the action runs. If there is an error, it should stop redirecting. I tried adding sforce.one.navigateToSObject on onComplete, which redirects even when there is error on the page resulting from the validations from the apex action on the command button. How can I make it redirect only when save actions runs successfully?

Comment: You should post your code, that would be helpful.

Comment: <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" rerender="id here" onComplete="sforce.one.navigateToSObject()?">

Comment: do you intend to use lightening framework (specifically aura components)? Or do you plan to use Visualforce pages in Salesforce1 app?

Comment: no aura components. just VF page. How would aura components help?

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so based on your comment, you've got a VF page and Controller.  You've got an action in the controller that returns void or null (since it's salesforce1).  You've got a command button in the VF page calling the action.

Probably the simplest thing you could do is in the oncomplete of the button, call a custom Javascript function. Like this one, which will handle the navigation.

```
<apex:form>

  <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" rerender="messages, othercontent" onComplete="postSave(); return false;">

  <apex:pagemessages id="messages" />

  <apex:outputPanel id="otherContent">
    {!Account.Name}
  </apex:outputPanel>

</apex:form>

<script>
    function postSave() {
        // here you just check to see the status of the save, you might be looking for the id of 
        // the record if it's insert, or something else if it's update.  If it's update, then 
        // setup a controller boolean property like "isSaveError" and set this in your save 
        // action, and check for that here.
        if('{!Account.id}' != ''){
            // the record saved, redirect
            sforce.one.navigateToSObject('{!Account.id}');            
        }
        // else, do nothing the error should be showing on page  
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I just added sforce.one.back(false);   in the postSave. It redirects correctly to the previous page in one/one.app in Chrome. But not on the actual device. The same code works on  <button onclick="sforce.one.back(false); return false;" >Cancel</button> sforce.one.navigateToSObject('{!Account.id}'); does not work either. Not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

This does not address your question directly with your current setup, but I have experienced a lot more control for this type of scenario with JavaScript remoting in Salesforce1. I do not know of any direct way to automatically navigate after using the standard commandButton component since it really isn't set up for client-side navigation (it would be great to be proven wrong!).

With JavaScript remoting you will need to do a lot more work for validation etc., but you gain control over taking action on a success or failure after the Controller method completes (will need to implement Save). There may be a better way to accomplish your goal, but consider this route as well:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/vf_dev_best_practices_approaches_remoting.htm